# Error IM002 [Microsoft][ODBC]Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: c#

My connection string,

```
string strConnection = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt;*.csv)};Dbq=" + this.dirCSV.Trim() + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False";
```

I am getting an error

> [Microsoft][ODBC]Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified.

Does anyone have any idea what's the solution for this.

Thanks,
Rushabh Shah.

Comment: What does the string look like AFTER it's built?

Answer (score 0):

As the error very clearly states, you must provide a data source in your connection string. For a text file, this is the path to your file. Please read an introduction to database connections, such as at [ASP 101](http://www.asp101.com/articles/john/connstring/default.asp).